# MediaPlayer stops working after 30 uses?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to write a function to play a short sound (in /res/raw) in my program, called at effectively random times throughout the program. So far I have this function:

```
public void playSound() {
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ShortBeep);
    mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mp.setLooping(false);
    mp.start();
}
```

It works fine for awhile, but after exactly 30 plays of the sound, it stops making sound.

Comment: Are you calling `mp.release()` anywhere?

Comment: You really have to give us more details about your setup, source code, LogaCt log Exceptions

Comment: Oh, I'm not calling mp.release(), would that cause this? Is there a limit for ~30 consecutive instances of mediaplayer?

Comment: Yeah, you need to make sure that you're releasing the player after you're done with it, even if the media itself has finished.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#releaseplayer

Answer (score 8):

[According to the Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#release%28%29)

> ... failure to call release() may cause subsequent instances of MediaPlayer objects to fallback to software implementations or fail altogether.

When you are done with it call `mp.release()` so that it can release the resources. I don't know what the limit is and I'm sure it depends on many factors. Either way you should be calling this function on your `MediaPlayer` object, especially if it will be used more than once.

Comment: I have 10 buttons all of them have their own MediaPlayer. When I press a button it plays a short sound. So what do you recommend, where to call release if I have the MediaPlayer.start() in an onClickListener? Thank you.

Comment: @Mitulátbáti So there are multiple instances of `MediaPlayer`? If there is only one `MediaPlayer` instance but it plays different sounds for different buttons then you could call `release()` in `onPause()`

Comment: Yes, all the buttons have an own MediaPlayer in View.OnClickListener defined (buttons generated in a loop). And in their onClick I call the start() method. But sadly I'm also facing this 30-times problem.

Comment: @Mitulátbáti can't you just use one global instance of `MediaPlayer` and play the sound needed depending on which button is clicked? That seems cleaner and easier

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try. Thanks for your help!

Comment: There's a fancy method I've just found: setOnCompletionListener in which I call release. It worked.

Comment: @Mitulátbáti I was going to suggest that but you would need set it for each button so I thought one instance would be easier then change the resource according to the button clicked. But I'm glad you got it figured out :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99740/discussion-between-mitulat-bati-and-codemagic).

Answer (score 1):

I've just solved the exact same problem, but I'm using Xamarin. I ended up changing from holding on to a MediaPlayer instance for the lifetime of the activity to creating an instance each time I want to play a sound. I also implemented the IOnPreparedListener and IOnCompletionListener.

Hopefully you can get the idea despite it being C# code

```
public class ScanBarcodeView :
    MvxActivity,
    MediaPlayer.IOnPreparedListener,
    MediaPlayer.IOnCompletionListener
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ScanBarcodeView);

        ((ScanBarcodeViewModel) ViewModel).BarcodeScanFailed += (sender, args) => PlaySound(Resource.Raw.fail);
        ((ScanBarcodeViewModel) ViewModel).DuplicateScan += (sender, args) => PlaySound(Resource.Raw.tryagain);
    }

    private void PlaySound(int resource)
    {
        var mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.SetDataSource(ApplicationContext, Android.Net.Uri.Parse($"android.resource://com.company.appname/{resource}"));
        mp.SetOnPreparedListener(this);
        mp.SetOnCompletionListener(this);
        mp.PrepareAsync();
    }

    public void OnPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
    {
        mp.Start();
    }

    public void OnCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
    {
        mp.Release();
    }
}
```

So, each time I want a sound to be played I create a MediaPlayer instance, so the data source, tell it that my Activity is the listener to Prepared and Completion events and prepare it. Since I'm using PrepareAsync I don't block the UI thread. When the media player is prepared the Start method on the MediaPlayer is called, and when the sound has finished playing the MediaPlayer object is released.

Before I made these changes I would get to 30 sounds played and it would all stop working. Now I've gone way past 30, also multiple sounds can be played simultaneously.

Hope that helps.